# CameraCaptureUI not showing the dialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio, camera, uwp, windows-10

I am trying to implement the CameraCaptureUI in my application and but it does not open any dialogue box. I do not get any error message. I followed the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-cameracaptureui). Following is the code:

```
CameraCaptureUI captureUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
captureUI.PhotoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIPhotoFormat.Jpeg;
captureUI.PhotoSettings.CroppedSizeInPixels = new Size(200, 200); 

StorageFile photo = await captureUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
```

I verified that the camera works through the Windows Camera app. I even tried various [sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh465152) provided by Microsoft and the camera does not open in any case.

Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Comment: Do you open the camera?

Comment: There is a similar question, please refer [Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI() does not open dialog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8ad65609-2e2d-4d64-bf92-09b86d54d393/uwp-windowsmediacapturecameracaptureui-does-not-open-dialog?forum=wpdevelop).